# number of months giving wrong results

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysql-error-1064

`membership` table

- membership_startdate
- member_dueday

To find the how many payments(number of months) that the members has paid up to now from `membership_startdate` and taking into consideration:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(GREATEST(NOW(), memberToMship_DueDay), memberToMship_StartDate) AS diff 
  FROM membertomship
```

...but it was giving wrong results when we consider `memberToMship_StartDate` is 2011-07-01 and the `mmebership_dueday` is  07     The result is 06, but it was wrong.

If `memberToMship_StartDate` is "2011-01-01" and the due date is 15 then the result is nearly 6 months (jan - jun) (according duedate 15th of month).

I am using mysql

I have tried this

```
                      SELECT DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(memberToMship_StartDate,GREATEST(NOW(), memberToMship_DueDay)), INTERVAL memberToMship_DueDay DAY ) AS diff FROM membertomships;
```

but it was giving error like

```
                 Error Code: 1064
                         You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GREATEST(NOW(), memberToMship_DueDay)), INTERVAL memberToMship_DueDay DAYS ) AS ' at line 1
```

Comment: @Tom i have tried but it was giving wrong results....

Comment: The example you gave would not give 7? DATEDIFF returns its result in days. So DATEDIFF('2011-07-01', '2011-01-01') will be 181

Comment: @justdanyul how to convert number of days in to months...

Comment: I am not asking the how many months are remaining , i am asking how many months has gone ...pls understand my question..

Comment: @user682417 What is a month 28, 30, or 31 days? What about leap years?

Comment: i have to consider those also...

Comment: @user682417 If that's the case that you need to be precise with your months calculation and not give an estimate, then I don't believe it is something you will be able to do easily in a single query. Ideally this is something you could surface to a higher level programming language outside the data layer, where it will be easier to deal with. If not you'll want to use a stored procedure or user defined function approach, so you can perform the multiple operations necessary to complete this calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here's the solution:

```
SELECT
    PERIOD_DIFF(DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y%m'), DATE_FORMAT(membership_StartDate,'%Y%m')) -- month difference
    + (DAY(membership_StartDate) < member_dueday) -- +1 if the start date was before the due day
    + (DAY(now()) > member_dueday) -- +1 if "now" is after the due day
    - 1 -- needed due to the way we are calculating our own adjustments for due day
    as payment_count
from membertomships;
```

Here's some test data to show the edge cases:

```
create table membertomships (id int auto_increment primary key, membership_startdate date, member_dueday int);
insert into membertomships values (null, '2011-05-01', 15);
insert into membertomships values (null, '2011-05-30', 15);
insert into membertomships values (null, '2011-05-01', 4);
insert into membertomships values (null, '2011-05-30', 4);
SELECT
    membership_StartDate as start,
    member_dueday as due,
    current_date as today,
    PERIOD_DIFF(DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y%m'), DATE_FORMAT(membership_StartDate,'%Y%m')) - 1 + (DAY(membership_StartDate) < member_dueday) + (DAY(now()) > member_dueday) as payment_count
from membertomships;
SELECT id, membership_StartDate as start_date, member_dueday as due_day, current_date as today,
PERIOD_DIFF(DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y%m'), DATE_FORMAT(membership_StartDate,'%Y%m')) - 1 + (DAY(membership_StartDate) < member_dueday) + (DAY(now()) > member_dueday) as payment_count
from membertomships;
+----+------------+---------+------------+---------------+
| id | start_date | due_day | today      | payment_count |
+----+------------+---------+------------+---------------+
|  1 | 2011-05-01 |      15 | 2011-07-08 |             2 |
|  2 | 2011-05-30 |      15 | 2011-07-08 |             1 |
|  3 | 2011-05-01 |       4 | 2011-07-08 |             3 |
|  4 | 2011-05-30 |       4 | 2011-07-08 |             2 |
+----+------------+---------+------------+---------------+
```

Comment: @Bohemain it was giving number of months like roundfigure 2 or 3 is it possible to get the exact number of months like 2.2 and 0.9 like this m

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure how you want to calculate it, show me the expected results for this set of data.

Comment: it includes comparison with due day and present day and results will be like  0.4 months and like 2.3 months , 2.5 months.....